# How can I improve this iptables

Tags: iptables, lan, routing

As a training, I'm trying to install a server with ESXi,

On this ESXi, I have a first ubuntu 16.04 VM that will be the firewall between WAN and LAN.

So the host machine IP is 192.168.1.25 and the main VM has 2 interfaces :

- ens160 (Wan side) 192.168.1.28
- ens192 (Lan side) 10.10.19.97

My Lan network is 10.10.19.96/27

On my "router" VM, I have installed and configure a DHCP and switch SSh from 22 to 9600.

I now have another VM (let's call VM2), on the LAN side and which will use the "router" VM to have access to the WAN.

I Wanted to have an apache server on the VM2 and redirection from :80 from "router" VM to VM2.

So I did this :

```
sudo echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.19.96/27 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens192 -o ens160
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o ens192 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o ens192 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.19.98:80
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o ens192 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.19.98:443
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 --p tcp -m tcp --dport 9600 -j ACCEPT
```

Those rules seems to be working, I can access the VM2 by VM1:80, I can access VM1 SSH on port 9600 and both VM can ping each other, the host machine, another computer, and google dns.

But I'm a beginner so I don't really trust myself, and want to know if there's something I missed, can be improved or shouldn't be done.

Comment: It looks just fine to me. I do not understand this line `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens192 -o ens160` and think that maybe you meant to write `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens192 -o ens160 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: The first time I did the rules I wrote it with "-j ACCEPT" but not on my file where I saved it. I didn't understand why it doesn't work anymore. Thanks ! ^^" Is the order of my rules correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think the order of your rules is O.K.